# Rational powers of real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I am reading the book of Professor Liebeck 'A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics'. In Chapter 4 the Rational Powers are defined. More specifically, the author considers the rational powers of real positive numbers. Are there any mathematical reasons to explain why the rational powers of real negative numbers are not treated in a book of this level?

Let $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ with $q=k/n$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. What is the proper domain of definition of $x^q$?

What are some textbooks that treat this issue?

Comment: Have you considered the example of $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the comment. Yes I know. For $n$ even the rational power x^{1/n} is not defined for x negative. But still there are other cases to consider.

Comment: But why bother talking about those other cases if it doesn't give us a continuous well-defined function?  If we restrict to positive numbers then exponentiation "*plays nice*" and gives us a function with many convenient properties that we want in functions (*differentiability, continuity, ...*).  Allowing negative numbers in the domain, even if only a few with specific allowable exponents, destroys that.

Comment: We run into trouble also in the case , say , $(-1)^{1/3}$. This is not just equal the third root of $-1$ since this rule holds only for nonnegative bases. It makes sense to define $x^r=e^{\ln(x)\cdot r}$ only for $x>0$ and possibly the special case $x=0$ with $0^r=0$ for every nonzero $r$.

Comment: "*What are some textbooks that treat this issue*" Probably any introductory textbook on complex analysis.

Comment: @JMoravitz I know that $(-8)^{3/2}$ is not defined (in reals). However, $(-8)^{2/3}=-4$ (taking the principal cubic root of a negative number to be a negative number).

Comment: @Dimitris is it though?  Is it not $(-2+2\sqrt{3} i)$?  Or what about $(-2-2\sqrt{3} i)$?  And what about if we wrote it with an exponent of $4/6$ instead of with an exponent of $2/3$?  The point is that a lot of rules we would normally have and enjoy for positive bases break down if we allow negative bases.  For instance $(a^b)^c$ is not necessarily equal to $a^{(bc)}$ anymore, or $a^b\cdot a^c$ is not necessarily $a^{b+c}$ anymore

Comment: @JMoravitz So, I guess it is better to stick with the rational powers of positive real numbers like the author:-)!

Comment: How did you get $(-8)^{2/3}=-4$?  If you stick to real cube roots then $\sqrt[3]{(-8)^2} = \sqrt[3]{64} = 4$ and $\left(\sqrt[3]{-8}\right)^2 = \left(-2\right)^2 =4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments were very helpful to clarify several things. Still, I post an answer to my principal question: Let $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ with $q=k/n$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. What is the proper domain of definition of $x^q$?. It is taken from the books [Fundamentals of University Mathematics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780857092236/fundamentals-of-university-mathematics). Note that the main result below follows a four pages discussion.

[image]

See the paragraph 1.5 in the following link (pages 11-16)

https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Fundamentals_of_University_Mathematics/GY1wAgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=Fundamentals+of+University+Mathematics+rational+powers&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover